# Is there any impact to changing IP address of MySQL Server?

Tags: mysql, configuration, mysql-5.1, network

We are changing the network and the IP addresses will be changing.
Will there be any impact to MySQL running on the server?

I don't use the IP address to reference the server.  Instead I use the server name.

For example:

Server          IP
MYPROD01        10.1.3.30 -> becomes -> 192.1.30.90

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the server name (DNS name) then a change of IP address will be used by your clients as soon as all DNS servers have this new address. Since you change your subnet you must be able to 'reach' this subnet from your clients. The only 'problem' can be that you loose the open connections.